# Typescript on VS13 stopped working after install VS15

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013

I use VS2013, with TypeScript Tools version 1.8.5.
Until installation of VS15 everything worked fine.
Since installing VS15, i can not compile the project in VS13,
I get thousands of compilation errors on *.d.ts files.
For example:

> Build: ';' Expected
>
> Build: Unexpected token; 'Parameter' expected
>
> Build: Unexpected token; 'Module, class, interface, enum, import or
>   statement' expected
>
> Build: Identifier expected
>
> Build:']' expected

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason, the problem was resolved when I installed the new version (2.2) of TypeScript Tools for VS15.